# The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed In Mqsql and Entity Framework

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I am doing From dropdown selection, I fill textboxes with the Json Value. Action() Method work fine It return Json value but page not populate these value to TextBoxes control. When i use Developer Tool then i get, it throw a Error **"The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed."**

**Controller**

```
    private hcEntities db = new hcEntities();

 // GET: Chains
 public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewData["chain_name"] = new SelectList(db.chains, "code", "name");
    return View(db.chains.ToList());
}

//Action Function callby javascript
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Action(string code)
{
    using (var ObjDb = new hcEntities())
    {
        var query = from c in ObjDb.chains
            where c.code == code
            select c;
        return Json(query);//Return Json Result
    }
}
```

**View:-**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function Action(code) {
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("Action", "Chains")',
    type: "POST",
    data: { "code": code },
    "success": function (data) {
        if (data != null) {
            var vdata = data;
            $("#ChainName").val(vdata[0].name);
            $("#ChainCode").val(vdata[0].code);
            $("#username").val(vdata[0].username);
        }
    }
});
}
```

Comment: try `return Json(query.ToList());`

Comment: i already used this it got exception "An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code"

Comment: Just for testing, get rid of the using and re-use your class level dbcontext in this line `var query = from c in db.chains`

Comment: when i use class level object i got this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26092390/mvc5-mqsql-issue

Comment: OK, I want to make sure you only have one dbcontext, so can you remove the class level one and add the `using (var db =  new hcEntities())` in all your controller methods then?

Comment: Can you add the stacktrace?

Comment: i perform another work with **dbcontext**, so i can't remove it.

Answer (score 1):

Try   `return Json(query.FirstOrDefault());`

Answer (score 0):

Use `IDisposable` again in the GET Controller:

```
 // GET: Chains
public ActionResult Index()
{
    using (var ObjDb = new hcEntities())
    {
       ViewData["chain_name"] = new SelectList(ObjDb.chains, "code", "name");
       return View(ObjDb.chains.ToList());
    }

}
```